# Can anti-holomorpic functions have poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an anti-holomorphic function, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$. I know that $f$ can be written as a power series in $\overline{z}$.

**Can $f$ have poles?**

EDIT:

I mean that $f$ has a pole in $p\in U$ iff locally $f$ can be written as $\frac{h(z)}{(z-p)^n}$ with $h(p)\neq 0$.

Comment: What's your definition of a pole for a non-holomorphic function?

Comment: Holomorphic and and anto-holomorphic theory are quite the same, because $f(z)$ is anti-holomorphic iff $\overline{f(z)}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: To amplify Robert Israel's comment: I've never seen a definition of "pole" in a context other than holomorphic functions. Nevertheless, I think there's a unique reasonable way to define a notion of pole for antiholomorphic $f$: A pole of such an $f$ should be defined as a pole of the holomorphic function $g$ defined by $g(z)=\overline{f(z)}$. (While I'm at it, the residue of $f$ at such a pole should be defined as the complex conjugate of the residue of $g$.)

Comment: my definition of a pole for an anti-holomorphic function is the same of that of a holomorphic one

Comment: @user10676: It depends exactly what you mean by _theory of anti-holomorphic functions_ and _quite the same_. For example, the set of anti-holomorphic maps is not closed under composition. This fact can be surprisingly vexing.